# will_paginate not creating URLs for pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I am using the [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem to create infinite scrolling.

The will_paginate gem usually creates links for each page depending on the data size.

I currently have 42 rows being fetched and i i have my `per_page` set to `per_page = 8`

Controller code:

```
page = params[:page]
per_page = 8

@ads = FbAd.get(current_users_user, page, per_page)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

model code:

```
ads = FbAd.active
              .select("fb_ads.id AS ad_id,
                     ac.fb_id AS creative_id,
                     acoss.source_page_id,
                     ald.link,
                     ald.call_to_action_type,
                     ald.message,
                     ald.name,
                     uass.url,
                     uass.file_type,
                     fbp.name AS page_name,
                     fbp.thumbnail_url")
              .where("fb_ads.user_id = ?", userId)
              .joins("INNER JOIN fb_adcreatives ac ON fb_ads.fb_adcreative_id = ac.id")
              .joins("INNER JOIN fb_adcreative_object_story_specs acoss ON ac.fb_adcreative_object_story_spec_id = acoss.id")
              .joins("INNER JOIN fb_adcreative_link_data ald ON ald.fb_adcreative_object_story_spec_id = acoss.id")
              .joins("INNER JOIN fb_assets ass ON ass.fb_id = ald.image_hash")
              .joins("INNER JOIN user_assets uass on uass.id = ass.user_asset_id")
              .joins("INNER JOIN fb_pages fbp on fbp.fb_id = acoss.source_page_id")
              .group("fb_ads.id, acoss.source_page_id, ald.link, ald.call_to_action_type, ald.message, ald.name, uass.url, 
                      uass.file_type, fbp.name, fbp.thumbnail_url, ac.fb_id")
              .paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)

    ads
```

My issue is that when the data is fetched, the gem is not creating any links for the next pages

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <section class="mt-7 mb-6">
    <div class="container" style="display: none;">

        <%= will_paginate @ads %>
    </div>        
  </section>
```

This is what the DOM looks like when i load the page:

[image]

I want to know if theres something i'm missing thats causing this issue, i have this same code working in this same project and i cant seem to figure out what i am missing or what can be causing this issue.

EDIT:

If i display the page_entries_info it says theres 1 record when theres 8 being displayed:

```
<div class="mt-5">
    <%= page_entries_info @ads %>

</div>
```

displays:

Displaying 1 Fb Ad

EDIT 2:

It has to do with my query. For some reason will_paginate thinks i have 1 record.

If i fetch just

`ads = FbAd.active.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)`

it generates the links.

I tried making just raw SQL and fetching it like this

```
ads = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
```

But that returns a hash and i need active record objects.

Comment: have you tested the object to be sure it has values? maybe the query is not correct. The function receives the first parameter current_users_user and in the query I see userId

Comment: @DiegoPatricioAguilefSánchez it has to do with the grouping, if i group for some reason it thinks theres only 1 record, if i remove the grouping it works like it should, when i get back to it i will post what i find for a fix